# Avoiding template parameter substitution completely

Tags: c++, templates, substitution, overload-resolution, tmp

I have a class that can accept arithmetic types and std::complex. A simplified code of the class is

```cpp
#include <complex>

template<typename T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
struct Foo {
    void foo(typename T::value_type t)
    requires (is_complex<T>::value) {
    }
};
```

Now, I would like to take the internal type of `std::complex` and use it as the type of the parameters in the `foo` function.For example, if T is std::complex<**double**>, then I want the parameter types to be `double`.

**This function should only be available when T is indeed `std::complex`**.

I thought I could use `typename T::value_type` as the parameter type, since `std::complex` has a typedef `value_type`. Plus, I thought using `requires` here would avoid T to be substitued in this function in case T wasn't std::complex. Silly me.
The issue is that whenever I create a `Foo<FundamentalType>` the code breaks, since fundamentals don't have `::value_type`.

```cpp
int main() {
    Foo<int> obj; // Breaks the code.
    //obj.foo(4); // Function shouldn't be considered in overload resolution ideally...

    Foo<std::complex<int>> obj2; // Works
    obj2.foo(4); // Works as expected
}
```

Ideally, I would like the substitution of T to be ignored for this function in case T is not std::complex. Is that possible? If not, how can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `is_complex`: you'd like the same here, but with a different body of the type. For example,

```
template<typename T> struct complex_value_type {};
template<typename T> struct complex_value_type<std::complex<T>> { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
using complex_value_type_t = typename complex_value_type<T>::type;
```

Then, at any point, you can call it as `complex_value_type_t<T>`:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {
    template<typename T_ = T>
    void foo(complex_value_type_t<T_> t)
    requires (is_complex<T_>::value) {
    }
};
```

The `requires` is not absolutely necessary then; it's already covered by `complex_value_type_t<T>` being defined only for `complex<T>`.

Comment: This is so simple yet so elegant. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work on any compiler I tried. You can't SFINAE away non-template functions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Pardon, indeed, template was not on function-level, but class level. Fixed using adding the template header.

Answer (score 1):

You just need *some* type to put in there, until `requires` can disable the function.

I would do this:

```
struct nullptr_value_type {using value_type = std::nullptr_t;};
```

```
using elem_or_null_t = typename std::conditional_t<is_complex<T>::value, T, nullptr_value_type>::value_type;
    
void foo(elem_or_null_t t)
requires (is_complex<T>::value)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a template class as a template parameter.

```
#include <complex>

template<template<class> class T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template<> struct is_complex<std::complex> : std::true_type {};

template<template<class> class T>
struct Foo {
    void foo(typename T<double>::value_type t)//could be typename<T<TT>> if you made foo a templated function
    requires (is_complex<T>::value) {
    }
};
int main(){
    Foo<std::complex> f;
};
```

But you will need what to put into it when used. I just hard-coded `double` but you have to add a new template parameter to `Foo` or make `foo` a templated member function